# Turning off mailing in psad

Tags: monitoring, psad

The `psad` monitoring tool keeps on sending lots of mail to my localhost admin account. I use my ubuntu server as a NAT router, and psad warned me to enable logging in iptables. After I did so, it sarted filling my mailbox with loads of messages. Within few days the size of mail box has grown to 3.4 GB.

How can I completely turn off mailing on psad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation: http://cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/config.html

You could set 'EMAIL_ADDRESSES' to a blackhole address (eg a receive address that just discards what it gets), or consider tuning the following:

'EMAIL_ALERT_DANGER_LEVEL'
'PSAD_EMAIL_LIMIT'
'EMAIL_LIMIT_STATUS_MSG'

Those are described in the URL I provided above. There are further email alerts for DShield as well, if you have that enabled - if so, they are also described in that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Under psad.conf:

```
### Allow reporting methods to be enabled/restricted.  This keyword can
### accept values of "nosyslog" (don't write any messages to syslog),
### "noemail" (don't send any email messages), or "ALL" (to generate both
### syslog and email messages).  "ALL" is the default.  Both "nosyslog"
### and "noemail" can be combined with a comma to disable all logging
### and alerting.
ALERTING_METHODS            ALL;
```

Note that changing `ALTERTING_METHODS` to `noemail` will stop all emails from psad.